# Need help generate PDF using ATK framework

Tags: php, atk4

for those  who are having knowledge in ATK framework. Can we generate PDF file using it? any answer will be helpful. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have looked at http://www.atk-framework.com/wiki/Basic_HTML_reports ?

Suggest you post your ATK Framework questions on the ATK Framework Forum as there are solutions there - eg

http://forum.achievo.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2788&hilit=fpdf